# Same...with construction

Tags: grammar

Can the adjective 'same' be followed by a prepositional phrase headed by 'with'? For instance,

> He went to the same school with me.
>
> She served in the same regiment with me.

Comment: Those sentences are acceptable only if they mean, "*He went with me to the same school*" and "*She served with me in the same regiment*", and even then, they're bad form because "same" and "with" is redundant. They do not mean, "*...the same school/regiment **as** me*".

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, if you mean that you and he went to the same school, the answer is No, that is incorrect. You have to say:

> He went to the same school as I did.

> He went to the same school as me.

Technically, the latter is incorrect (should be "I", not "me"), but it has become acceptable in modern spoken English. In fact, if I were speaking among friends, that's what I would say. People would look at me funny if I said "I" instead of "me".

Similarly, in your second example, this is the correct sentence:

> She served in the same regiment as I [did].

But in spoken English, a majority of people will say:

> She served in the same regiment as me.

Comment: '...the same school as I did' sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my answer above.